# Reputation points for dewikified answers

Tags: support, reputation, community-wiki

If my answer is made community wiki because I revised it too many times, and if I get a moderator to dewikify it, will I eventually get the reputation points for upvotes received while the answer was CW, and if so how long does that take?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that you do, so long as it's relatively quick, but I'm not really sure, so...

If it does work, it shouldn't take very long. The reputation is supposed to be updated in near real time.